# Imports while testing with Jest fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

so I have React component that works well in the browser, but fails to render while testing. I am using Jest, and the component in question is a wrapper around [React Sortable](https://github.com/cheton/react-sortable). While trying to launch the test, I get "_sortablejs2.default.create is not a function" error, which I have found out that is caused by imports (i.e. require('react')) in Sortable.js file returning 'undefined'. Why might that be? Other tests that I have work just fine.

Test itself:

```
let renderer = TestRenderer.create(
      <DragAndDropSelector
        selected={[]}
        choices={[]}
        selectedChange={ (a, b, c) => {return a} }
      />
  );
  expect(renderer.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

My package json:

```
{
"name": "<Redacted/>",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.17.1",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.3",
    "faker": "4.1.0",
    "file-saver": "1.3.8",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "html-to-react": "1.3.3",
    "immutability-helper": "2.6.6",
    "lodash": "4.17.5",
    "moment": "2.21.0",
    "npm": "6.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "2.1.4",
    "react-datepicker": "1.4.1",
    "react-dates": "16.6.1",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.3.0",
    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "react-sortablejs": "^1.3.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-dehydrate": "0.0.2",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "5.6.5",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "semantic-ui": "2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "0.78.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "less-watch-compiler --run-once src src",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && less-watch-compiler src src",
    "start-js": "PORT=3000 react-scripts start --host 0.0.0.0",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "less-watch-compiler": "1.11.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.1",
    "serve": "6.5.3"
},
"homepage__doc": "See VERSION in config/config.js, version should be the same",
"homepage": "/2.1/"
```

}

Im stumped, so any help would be appreciated:)

EDIT: As per request, more detailed error message:

```
TypeError: _sortablejs2.default.create is not a function    
at Sortable.componentDidMount (/home/path/node_modules/react-sortablejs/lib/Sortable.js:120:50)
at commitLifeCycles (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4553:24)
at commitAllLifeCycles (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5729:9)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallback$1 (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1559:10)
at invokeGuardedCallback (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:1506:29)
at commitRoot (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5833:9)
at performWorkOnRoot (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6800:42)
at performWork (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6750:7)
at requestWork (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6661:7)
at scheduleWorkImpl (/home/path/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6515:11)
```

More info: 
In react-sortablejs/lib/Sortable.js file, in line

```
var _sortablejs = require('sortablejs');
```

require returns undefined. However, I have sortablejs installed, I can see it with my very own eyes in the node modules. I even checked that it does get entered when rendering in browser, but not when running tests. I am stumped, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting?

Comment: Sure, edited my post:)

Comment: Documentation states that in React the import should be: `import Sortable from 'react-sortablejs';`

Comment: No doubt about that, however we are talking about the compiled (into js) code of a module that I have downloaded. And it works in the browser, but not during tests, so... any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: i have same problem. any solution here?

Comment: sadly, since we needed only a simple functionality we implemented it ourselves, giving up on sortablejs:)